# Sharepoint sign out programatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have FBA enable in my sharepoint site. I want to do custom log out. I found below code.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
 var authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        // Clear .ASPAUTH cookie key.
 if (authCookie != null)
 {
  var myCookie = new HttpCookie(authCookie.Name)
               {Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)};
  Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
 }

 SPIisSettings iisSettingsWithFallback = 

 Site.WebApplication.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(Site.Zone);
 if (iisSettingsWithFallback.UseClaimsAuthentication)
 {
  FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
                // Clear FedAuth Cookie key
  FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSession       
 TokenCookie();
 }
```

But I am getting FederatedAuthentication does not exist in the context. For that i have to add Microsoft.Sharepoint.IdentityModel.Service.dll/System.IdentityModel.Service.dlll. 
**From where can i add this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think class that you need locates here:

```
//Type: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedAuthentication
//Assembly: Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
//Assembly location: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.IdentityModel\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll
```

Also, you could try that code to do sign out:

```
public static void SignOut(HttpContext context)
{
  FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  if (context == null)
    return;
  context.Response.Redirect("{HomePageUrl}", false);
}
```